# Dropdown in ActionBar backwards compatibilty

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I would like to use a dropdown (spinner) in my actionbar, like in the image below. But I'm wondering about the backwards compatibility (`android < 3` ).

[image: Dropdown]

Is there any kind of native backwards compatibility, like with the menu-items in the action bar, or is using a 3rd party library (like [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com)) my only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [the AppCompat action bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setListNavigationCallbacks%28android.widget.SpinnerAdapter,%20android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener%29) and ActionBarSherlock support drop-down list navigation. However, configuring it requires an `ActionBar`, so you will need one of those two backports.